# Как изменится предложение?

Tags: стилистика

Как изменится предложение "Скоро в магазин  привезут новые товары", если слово "привезут" заменить словом "поступят"?

Answer (score 1):

Из односоставного неопределённо — личного оно превратится в двусоставное.

Comment: Согласна с предыдущим комментарием.